# How to Access Entity collection in Hibernate?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, associations

```
@Entity 
@Table (name="USER_DETAIL")
public class AccountBean {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;                                         
private String name;
private String description;  

@OneToMany
private List<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<Address>();

//with all getter and setter 
}
```

Address class:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int addId;
@Column (name="HOUSE_NUMBER")
private int houseNumber;
@Column (name="CITY_NAME")
private String city;
@Column (name="STATE_NAME")
private String state;
@Column (name="PIN_ZIP")    
private int zip;
 // with all getter setter 
}
```

How to access collection of Address data from AccountBean Entity class while all data will be saved in AccountBean Entity class only and Address Entity class associated with Accountbean class

Answer (score 1):

Currently you don't have Address Entity associated with AccountBean only the other way around (so it is one-directional relationship, as defined in your code).
So, you define a field of type AccountBean with a @ManyToOne relationship on it, and then you enhanced your @OneToMany relationship like this 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Address>", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})

Now when you retrieve an object of type AccountBean from DB, it will automatically have the List of Address entities populated (if any defined). When you add a new Address to the list, and merge the AccountBean, it will automatically persist the new Address entity and associate it to AccountBean object